# how to verify if a use-case fits in my design?

Tags: process, mapping, use-case

We have designed an application, actually a framework, keeping few use-cases/scenarios in-mind. Now we want to verify our design with few other use cases?

Are there any tools - probably process tools - to verify if the use cases out there fits into our design?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can always write a testcase for each new scenario and take it from there.

If you are interested in tools, Fitnesse (http://fitnesse.org/) is a well known test acceptance framework which you can use to document behavior and map it to automated test cases. It will allow you to define tests using simple sentences, group them in hierarchies, and then put simple implementations (Junit, TestNG, etc.) behind each statement.